# printSchema() not working for dataframe created from pandas (using Python)

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have worked with Dataframe being created from SparkSession (by spark.read) where I could print the schema of dataframe with printSchema().

However, when I create a Dataframe from pandas, I am getting error to use this method. Error message at the bottom.

Questions:

1. What can I use here to get schema of the dataframe
2. Are dataframe attributes different when created from pandas than from SparkSession?
   Error message: *

Traceback (most recent call last): File "/Users/gautamde/code/df_pd.py", line 6, in print(df.printSchema()) File "/Users/gautamde/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 5487, in getattr return object.getattribute(self, name) AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'printSchema'

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

1. You can use [`df.info`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.info.html) to get the schema of a pandas DataFrame.
2. Yes there is a difference between a pandas DataFrame and a Spark DataFrame. There is even a pandas on Spark DataFrame.

- https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.html
- https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html
- https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.1/api/python/reference/pyspark.pandas/api/pyspark.pandas.DataFrame.spark.frame.html